# C-style array constexpr qualifications by variadic template initializer

Tags: c++, c++17

In the following example, it seems the elements of `a` don't qualify as constexpr.

```
template <int ...n>
struct A
{   static constexpr int a[] {n...};
};

int main()
{   A<0> b;
    constexpr int a = b.a[0];
}
```

The above does not compile. Clang (edit: specifically ARM Apple Clang 12.0.5) says 'indexing of array without known bound is not allowed in a constant expression'. This seems unintuitive; the size of the array and thereby the index bound is clearly `sizeof...(n)`, no?

When explicitly setting `a`'s size by `static constexpr int a[sizeof...(n)] {n...}` it does compile.

What's going on here? Why don't these produce the same behavior? I thought the size gets inferred from the initializer list's length.

Comment: `constexpr int b.a[0];` is not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, even with the oldest clang version that supports `constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/P9ePxM19o

Comment: Interesting! I'm using Apple Clang. I can 100% confirm it does not compile on ARM Apple Clang 12.0.5. Compiler bug?

Comment: Installed ARM GGC 10.2.1, does work now, so likely unrelated to architecture.

Comment: Apple Clang != Clang.  I've never used it, but I've heard Apple Clang is quite a bit buggier and less standard-compliant.

Comment: So it would seem. I will send a bug report.